# Listview with type face

Tags: android, listview, typeface

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
View v = listView.getChildAt(0);
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "a.ttf");
((TextView) v).setTypeface(typeface);
```

what is problem in it ?

Comment: Good question. What is the problem? What are you trying to do? Is your code not compiling, does it throw an error at runtime or is it just not behaving as expected?

Comment: em trying to access items of listview and throwing them differents type face on each item but when i run the application it stop crash ?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException:

Answer (score 1):

You can't set custom font to list view like that way. First of all you need to create your own custom adapter for the list view. And you need to set the custom font in the `getView` method of your custom adapter. Example:

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {
     View v = convertView;
     if(v == null)
     {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
     }

     // Setting custom font to text view
     TextView titleText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
     Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "a.ttf");
     titleText.setTypeface(typeface);

     // Do other stuffs

    return v;
}
```

Comment: It will do that for all items here i am trying to give different font to different items ? how i do that

Comment: @JawadZahid: You can check the position and set different fonts accordingly

Comment: for position i have to use onitemclicklistener but this will change the fonts after i click the list item how i do without clicking ?

Comment: @jawadzahid: why? Did you check the code I've added above? Check the first parameter. You can achieve it with custom adapter. I think you should read a tutorial about custom adapter, before doing it.